# Finding one file without extension from other files with same name but different file type

Tags: python, bash

I have a folder with many different files in it all called report.  Some without file extensions.

[image]

I need to move the pdf report to another folder using python or bash.

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: looks like the extensions are hidden (check the display options), you cannot have the same names inside one folder

Comment: These files HAVE extensions, go to command prompt, to their directory and run 
"dir"

Comment: like the other people are saying, the PDF is a .pdf, your windows settings is whats hiding the extensions

Comment: Thanks Sorry for the dumb question.  I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

If all you're doing is moving to another folder, I would recommend bash since it is such a simple operation

```
#!/bin/bash
mv report.pdf /path/to/new/folder
```

Comment: To be pedantic, `mv` is not a bash command, it's part of the coreutils package (for GNU linux anyway)

Comment: @glenn jackman; Oh please do be pedantic.  Personally, I find the distinction to be useless since I operate exclusively on GNU linux systems, but this is EXACTLY the type of thing that will bite you if not careful.  I appreciate your distinction.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with AllenMoh's answer for bash.  Since the OP asked about Python as well, here is the Python solution.

```
import shutil
import os

src = '/path/report.pdf'
dst = '/new_path/'

shutil.move(src, dst)

# alternative, if destination is on current file system, you can use rename
# notice here the filename is specified
dst = '/new_path/report.pdf' 

os.rename(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Python-Magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/blob/master/magic.py) library help to find the file type.

Read all the filesnames in loop and pass it to `magic.from_file("filename")` and check the output to see if it is a pdf.
If pdf then move it to destination directory.

This api doesnot depend on the file extension.